# Erro " indirect fixture" ao usar pytest com uma função fatorial em python

Tags: python, python-3.x, testes-automatizados

Estou estudando recursão e testes automatizados e resolvi implementar um fatorial recursivo:

```
   def fatorial(n):
    if n <= 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return n*fatorial(n - 1)


import pytest

@pytest.mark.parametrize("entrada","esperado",[
    (0,1),
    (1,1),
    (2,2),
    (3,6),
    (4,24),
    (5,120)
])

def testa_fatorial(entrada,esperado):
    assert fatorial(entrada)  == esperado
```

Não sei o motivo de o pytest estar apresentando o erro:

```
 ERROR collecting Fatorial_pytest.py ____________________________________________________________________
In testa_fatorial: indirect fixture '(0, 1)' doesn't exist
```

Aparentemente, o teste está correto. Alguma ideia?
Estou utilizando o python 3.7 no windows 10 64 bits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenta colocar tudo em uma única linha:

`@pytest.mark.parametrize("entrada","esperado",[(0,1),(1,1),(2,2),(3,6),(4,24),(5,120)])`

ou então acresentar uma `\`ao final de cada linha pra dizer pro python que o comando continua na linha seguinte.

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize("entrada","esperado",[\
    (0,1),\
    (1,1),\
    (2,2),\
    (3,6),\
    (4,24),\
    (5,120)\
]
```